# How can I continue displaying a tooltip when it hovers over text in a d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 Mercator map. In the center of each area, there is text with the name of the area. I also have a tooltip with more information about the area. It is working properly except the tooltip does not display when I hover over the text. How can I define the text to avoid this?

```
paths.selectAll("text")
.data(wards.features)
.enter().append("svg:text")
.text(function(d){
    return (d.properties.SCODE_NAME);
    })
.attr("x", function(d){
    return path2.centroid(d)[0];
    })
.attr("y", function(d){
    return  path2.centroid(d)[1];
    })
.attr("text-anchor","middle")
.attr("font-size","24px");
```

Answer (score 0):

.attr("pointer-events", "none") solved my problem.